# ASP.NET MVC, CRUD 2 tables 1 with foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, crud

I have 2 tables contract and account in my database, I want to modify the contract table only if the account code is in the account table.

The tables are created in the database already. I have 2 entities in my mvc application:

Contract entity:

```
  public class Contract
     {
         [Key]
         [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
         public int ContractID { get; set; }

         [Display(Name = "Account Code")]
         //[ForeignKey("AccountCode")] 
         public string AccountCode { get; set; }
         //public virtual Account AccountCode { get; set; }

         [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
         public string ProductCode { get; set; }

     }
```

In my Accounts entity:

```
 public class Accounts
     {
        [Key]
         public string AccountCode { get; set; }
         public string CompanyName { get; set; }
         public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
         public string VATNumber { get; set; }
         public string Telephone { get; set; }
         public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
         public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
         public string City { get; set; }
         public string County { get; set; }
         public string PostCode { get; set; }
         public string Country { get; set; }

         //public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contract { get; set; } 
     }
```

The CRUD is working currently without the foreign keys as I have commented them out.

I have a foreign key (AccountCode)in the database on the contract table linking to the accounts table. How do I implement that on my mvc application with my entities above? 
I have read google and tried the commentted code above without any success.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you

```
   public class Contract
         {   
             [Key]
             [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
             public int ContractID { get; set; }
             public virtual Account Account{ get; set; }
             [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
             public string ProductCode { get; set; }
             public string AccountAccountCode {get;set;} 
 //automatically treated as foreign key of Account[Notice ClassNameKey Format]

     }
```